# How to make OpenLayers (5.3.3) work in a VisualStudio/Asp.Net.Core/TypeScript environment

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, openlayers-5

As stated in the headline I would like to use the current version of OpenLayers via TypeScript in a Asp.Net.Core project.

I downloaded OpenLayers via `npm install ol`.
This package does NOT contain a `ol.js` file NOR any type definition files (`*.d.ts`) for TypeScript.

So it seems the `*.js/*.ts`-files have to be built myself. I did not find any documentation on how to do that and/or how to make type information available for Visual Studio intellisense and TypeScript.

The whole build process must also work on TFS's continous integration builds, therefore i cannot install any third party tools etc.

All i have so far is the `ol`-folder in `node_modules` without a `ol.js`-file and no type information.

Comment: You don't have to built it yourself, just include it in your project. If you are using some bundler (webpack, systemjs, angular-cli etc.) it will compile and bundle the files for you. If not, then well you need bundling. should work w/o it too, then you need some kind of task (i.e. grunt or gulp) manager to copy the files to the desired folders, but websites requesting many small *.js files tend to be slow, bundling is the way to go in 2019

Comment: The current paradigm is just to add the type script files/exports with `Import 'ol/Map'`, then the Map class becomes available in your *.ts file. When your application is bundled, it will look for all imports and pick that files also into the bundling process. Gone are old JavaScript times, where you load/include dozens of *.js files in your html code :P Also see npm page for instructions and samples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol

Comment: well i am currently using the [asp.net core builtin bundler/minifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) which afaik does not scan *.ts/*.js files to determine dependencies. so i have to replace this by the npmjs bundler?